# не получается обратиться к элементу из-за автообновления страницы

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Не получается обратится к элементу страницы, так-как блок, в котором находится элемент, постоянно каждые несколько секунд обновляется.

UPD: Я выяснил, что оно обновляется, из-за приходящих get запросов. Теперь у меня другой вопрос, можно ли через Selenium сделать блокировку запросов или самому отловить приходящий json.
[image]
[image: Наивысшая цена авто покупки]

Вот код:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(visibility_of(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]")))

firstcost = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]").text.replace(' руб.','')
```

Вот ошибка:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3](https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Bowie%20Knife%20%7C%20Tiger%20Tooth%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29)/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]

Страница, с которой я работаю: [тык](https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Bowie%20Knife%20%7C%20Tiger%20Tooth%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29)

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, насколько вижу, у вас неправильный путь указан. Xpath можно напрямую в консоли разработчика вставлять и смотреть селект элемента. Правильный /html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]. Как вариант можно отталкиваться от id элеметов и не завязываться на последовательности из кучи тэгов. Другое возможное решение, если элемент не находится, повесить обработку в setInterval или иначе асинхронно проверять наличие элемента. Но думаю, в вашем случае, просто неправильно указали XPath

Comment: Xpath указан верный, только что перепроверил, если в поиске HTML его ввести, все находит. Но скрипт не работает, с аналогичным элементом все находит верно, но его браузер не обновляет постоянно, поэтому проблема именно из-за обновления. Попробовал путь указать через селектор, все тоже самое.

Comment: Поищите в гугле, как отключить javascript через selenium. Не хочу здесь оставлять линки, думаю найти будет несложно. Часть ответов сводится к отключению обработки js на уровне самого браузера. Если обключить js, то данные просто не будут обновляться.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему тем, что отловил приходящий get запрос при загрузке страницы.

```
import requests as req
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def run(playwright, link):
    links = []
    firefox = playwright.firefox
    browser = firefox.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.on("request", lambda request: links.append(request.url))
    page.goto(link)
    browser.close()
    #Ниже я уже достаю нужную для себя ссылку
    ans = links[-1]
    txt = ans.find('currency=')
    if ans[txt + len('currency=')] == '1':
        ans = ans.replace('1', '5', 1)
    res = req.get(ans)
    data = res.json()
    return data

link = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Bowie%20Knife%20%7C%20Tiger%20Tooth%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29'

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    data = run(playwright, link)
```